# C# receive error sending a email

Tags: c#, smtpclient

> ERROR: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Resources temporarily unavailable - Please try again later

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string smtpAddress = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    int portNumber = 587;
    bool enableSSL = true;

    string emailFrom = "mail@yahoo.com";
    string password = "mailpass";
    string emailTo = "sendemail@yahoo.com";
    string subject = "Hello";
    string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
        mail.To.Add(emailTo);
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        //mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // Can set to false, if you are sending pure text.

        // mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
        //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeZip.zip"));

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
            smtp.Send(mail);

        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/resources-temporarily---numeric-code-sln5083.html like the message says, why not queue the requests and try again later

Comment: yes, he allow you  to do that, i do that some months ago and it work, but i lost the code

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure an external application has permission to send emails through your email before you can proceed.

Comment: i had permission, i do that some months ago with the same email, but now idk why dosn' t work

Comment: Try disabling your antivirus.

Comment: I have Avast, he have mail Shield, i disable it but still don't work

Comment: Check the permissions again on the email account. It could have been reset. Also, make sure nothing is in the outbox on your email account. If none of those are the issues, then try again at a later time and see if it still doesnt work.

Comment: i check it, https://login.yahoo.com/account/security?.scrumb=JDdTM27im.9, still don't work, i will try after a few hours